# subtraction of two multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Assume that we have a $n$-dimensional vector that shows the position of a point and two multivariate normal distributions with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and covariances $cov_1$ and $cov_2$.

I’m trying to find a formula to calculate the subtraction of the distance between that point and each of those multivariate normal distributions.

Or if let me know how can I have subtraction of two different multivariate normal distribution.

I'd be really thankful if someone explain it for me.

Comment: Please consider this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables If I understand your question properly, it is easily searchable on the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly response. However I suppose that there are some different between my question and that wikipedia address.

Comment: Then formulate your question in a way so that it is understandable what the problem is.